# creating double sided arrow with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows

Ho can I make a figure like the following with tikz package?

[image]

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{arrows}`, `style={<->}`?  Is that what you were asking?